# Failed to find data source com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have written a python script in which spark reads the streaming data from kafka and then save that data to mongodb.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import time
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,TimestampType, DoubleType, StringType, StructField
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext


#the name to the topic that the consumer needs to receive messages from- same topic that the producer feeds the messages to. We also set the kafka server and port and start a Spark session.

kafka_topic_name = "pkttest_pcap"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:9092'


#spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Structured Streaming Pkt").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession \
   .builder \
   .appName("Spark") \
   .master('local')\
   .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector:10.1.1') \
   .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0') \
   .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("Error")

#construt a streaming dataframe that reads from topic
pkt_df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers).option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name).load()

pkt_df1 = pkt_df.selectExpr("CAST(value as String)", "timestamp")

schemaPacket = StructType([ \
   StructField("count",StringType(),True), \
   StructField("src_ip",StringType(), True), \
   StructField("dst_ip",StringType(), True), \
   StructField("proto",StringType(), True), \
   StructField("sport",StringType(), True), \
   StructField("dport",StringType(), True)])

schemaKafka = StructType([ \
   StructField("payload",StringType(),True)])

pktDF=pkt_df1.select(from_json(col('value'),schemaKafka).alias("json_data")).selectExpr('json_data.*')

pktDF=pktDF.select(from_json(col('payload'),schemaPacket).alias("json_data2")).selectExpr('json_data2.*')

dsw = (
 pktDF.writeStream
   .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
   .queryName("ToMDB")
   .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/pyspark7/")
   .option("forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation", "true")
   .option('spark.mongodb.connection.uri','mongodb+srv://<>:<>@batchdata.niq660y.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
   .option('spark.mongodb.database', 'BatchData')
   .option('spark.mongodb.collection', 'Traffic')
   .outputMode("append")
   .start().awaitTermination());
```

When i run the code using spark submit ** spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0 spark-consumer-pcap.py**, errors come:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unknown/Hani/Paralell-Processing/Spark/spark-consumer-pcap.py", line 66, in <module>
    pktDF.writeStream
  File "/home/unknown/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 1389, in start
  File "/home/unknown/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "/home/unknown/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
  File "/home/unknown/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.start.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:574)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:675)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.startInternal(DataStreamWriter.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:249)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.DefaultSource
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:661)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:661)
        at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:661)
        ... 14 more
```

I have been stuck on this problem for a long time. Please help

Comment: `spark.jars.packages` takes a comma-separated list. You are overriding the config by setting it twice. But also, do you really need Spark? Mongo provides a Kafka Connect utility

Comment: I have to use spark for machine learning the batches that are coming from kafka,i tried your solution but the error still remains

Comment: Since the data is coming from Kafka, then you can try to use Kafka Connect framework, was my point. "Batches" or "machine learning" doesn't really matter. In any case, what version of Spark are you using?